# Let $F$ be a field and $f \in F[x]$. Prove that $\left\{ g(f(x)):g\in F[x]\right\}$ is equal to $F[x]$ if and only if $deg(f)=1$.

Tags: polynomials, field-theory

I am trying to solve the following exercise

> Let $F$ be a field and $f \in F[x]$. Prove that $\left\{ g(f(x)):g\in
>  F[x]\right\}$ is equal to $F[x]$ if and only if $deg(f)=1$.

I have only managed to show that if $deg(f) = 0$ then $\left\{ g(f(x)):g\in
 F[x]\right\}=F$. Need hint for other part of proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\deg f>1$ show that the set contains no polynomial of degree %1%.

If $\deg f=1$, say $f(x)=ax+b$ with $a\ne 0$, then $g\circ h\circ f=g$ if $h(x)=\frac 1a x-\frac ba$.